# Throttling watched input with jquery and lodash

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, lodash, throttling

**Problem:** Using `_.throttle` I lose the ability to pass `$(this)` to the target function.

I'm using jQuery to watch 3 separate `input` fields.

I'd like the output function to update the output area, but in a controlled manner, it doesn't need to update immediately.

**Example:**

```
$("input").on("change input paste keyup",
    _.throttle( output( $(this).val() )
));
```

**Result:** A jQuery error occurs, because `this` is undefined.

**Notes:** Moving `_.throttle()` to an anonymous function called by `on()` just fires `output` immediately.

I've tried a variety of setups, but none have worked for me. I feel as though I'm overlooking something very obvious.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** Passing a function reference preserves the usage of `this`.

**example:**

```js
function output() {
  var x = $(this).val();
  $("#output").val(x);
}

// Watch input and throttle calls to output
$("input").on("change input paste keyup", _.throttle(output, 350));
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Type here" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <textarea id="output" rows=4 class="form-control" placeholder="Output here"></textarea>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Source:**
I google-fu'd some more and found the [answer in an article](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/) I had already skimmed over, but did not "read".

---

@[Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824112/) : Unfortunately your code doesn't work on first principle. You can't declare a variable the way that you did, in the spot that you did.

I'm guessing you may have meant to say either this:

```
// this will not work
$("input").on("change input paste keyup",
    self = this,
    // this throws an error
    _.throttle( output( $(self).val() ) )
);
```

**or this:**

```
//This does not work either
$("input").on("change input paste keyup", function(){
    self = this;
    // this still throws an error
    _.throttle( output( $(self).val() ) );
});
```

**They both throw the same error.**

Answer (score 0):

Cache `this`

```
$("input").on("change input paste keyup",
    var self = this;
    _.throttle( output( $(self).val() )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the bind method to catch the value you want to pass:

```
$("input").on("change input paste keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var boundOutput = output.bind(this, value);
  _.throttle( boundOutput );
});
```